# What's the meaning of groupies and throwing stars in this paragraph from Rework by Jason Fried?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the meaning of *groupies* and *throwing stars* means in this paragraph from [Rework by Jason Fried and David Heinemeier Hansson](https://books.google.com/books?id=U77um_h_dgcC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=At%20this%20stage,%20its%20silly%20to%20worry%20about%20whether%20or%20not%20your%20concept%20will%20scale%20from%20five%20to%20five%20thousand%20people%20or%20from%20a%20hundred%20thousand%20to%20100%20million%20people.%20Getting%20a%20product%20or%20service%20off%20the%20ground%20is%20hard%20enough%20without%20inventing%20even%20more%20obstacles.#v=onepage&q=At%20this%20stage%2C%20its%20silly%20to%20worry%20about%20whether%20or%20not%20your%20concept%20will%20scale%20from%20five%20to%20five%20thousand%20people%20or%20from%20a%20hundred%20thousand%20to%20100%20million%20people.%20Getting%20a%20product%20or%20service%20off%20the%20ground%20is%20hard%20enough%20without%20inventing%20even%20more%20obstacles.&f=false):

A lot of companies post help-wanted ads seeking "rock stars" or ninjas." Lame. Unless your workplace is filled with **groupies** and **throwing stars**, these words have nothing to do with your business.

Actually, I don't understand the concept of the last sentence. What does authors want to say?

Answer (score 4):

A groupie is a fan of a particular rock star, and a [throwing star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuriken) is a weapon associated with the ninja.

The author is attacking just the lame metaphor used in some job postings of calling the the very best programmers "rock stars" and "ninjas", and is suggesting that only real rock stars (with groupies) should be called rock stars, and that only real ninjas (with shuriken) should be called ninja.

Answer (score 1):

It's using satire to mock the people who misuse hyperbole to inflate the importance of some of their employees.

*Groupies* are excited fans who hang around the backstage areas of rock concerts, trying to meet the band members, often for the reason of a brief sexual encounter. The paragraph is mocking the concept of calling a highly qualified employee a "rock star" because there is obviously not a group of fans waiting around your office wanting to have sex with your best accountant or your best programmer. Similarly, calling your network engineers *ninjas* doesn't actually mean they wear black robes and throw little metal weapons to assassinate people in the dark of night.